# Second div is showing up underneeth relatively positioned div

Tags: html, css, position

I want the **bottom-wrapper** div to show up below **top-wrapper** div (like normal order).
Right now it's showing up underneeth the **top-wrapper**

What am I doing wrong here?

http://jsfiddle.net/uqtZ5/

HTML

```
<div id='top-wrapper'>
    <a href='#'>Title to overlay</a>
    <img src='image.jpg' />
</div>
<div id='bottom-wrapper'>
    <a href='#'><h3>Header</h3></a>
    <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#top-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#top-wrapper a,
#top-wrapper img {
    position: absolute;
}

#top-wrapper a {
    background-color:#FF0000;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: It's because the image is absolutely positioned, this puts it out of the normal "flow" of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a and img in top-wrapper position to be absolute.

In this case the position is absolute in relatively positioned DIV but you didn't set the height of top-wrapper so absolute positioned content comes over div bottom-wrapper. Try to specify the top-wrapper height to match img height and see if that solves your problem.

So try this:

```
#top-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    height: 216px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works obviously. My bad, forgot to mention that the height of the image is dynamic. Is that possible at all?